# Can a private function of a class be called from a local function?

Tags: c++, oop, class, object

Simplification of the code to express the concept:

```
class classA
{

public:

private:
   int a;
   seta(int x);
};

//local prototype
void somefunction();

int main()
{
  classA object; //create an object of the class

  somefunction(object);
  return 0;
}

void somefunction(classA &object)
{

  object.seta(5);    
}
```

}

If I move `seta()` to the public section of the class there is no error and it executes.

However, if I move `seta()` to the private section, I get the following error:

> error C2248:
>    '`anonymous-namespace'::classA::seta' : cannot access
>   private member declared in class '`anonymous-namespace'::classA'

If the function is private and only this class is calling it, why is there an issue?

**EDIT** I am passing the object from main to the local function

Comment: Your comment in main is wrong - you're creating an instance of a class (which is an object), not creating a class.

Comment: `void main()` should be `int main()`.

Comment: You obviously have a misunderstanding of what private means. The example you quote is clearly illegal, and I struggling to imagine why you think it should be OK. Perhaps you need to explain your reasoning if you want to gain some understanding. Or just make somefunction a friend of of classA if you want to call private methods from it.

Comment: @john: I figured from the error that this is the case but wanted to get as much feed back and explanation as possible so posted the question open ended without stating any ideas of how I think it should work, whether right or wrong.

Comment: @Tommy: People have a lot of misunderstandings about public and private, usually because they misunderstand the purpose. The point of public and private is to seperate the interface of a class (broadly speaking it's public members) from it's implementation so that the implementation can change without the code using the class also having to change.

Comment: Ok I see now, thank you for the knowledge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function that is calling `seta()` is not part of `classA`, so this is an error; that's the very definition of `private`. If you were to make `somefunction()` a member of `classA`, or declare it to be a `friend` of `classA`, then this would work.

Answer (score 2):

The function `somefunction()` is not a member function of `classA`.  It's a function with global scope and cannot access the private function `seta()`, just as `main()` cannot access the private function `seta()`.

Answer (score 1):

Private members can only be accessed by it's members and it's friends. Also every member function in C++, should have a return type. With that said -

```
void main() // 1
{
  classA object; //2

  somefunction();
}
```

1. Return type of `main` should be **int**.
2. Scope of `object` is only in `main` and cannot be accessed in `somefunction` with out explicitly passing it to the function.

---

On your Edit:

You are passing `object` to `somefunction(classA)` by value. So, a copy of the `object` ( main scoped) is made to `somefunction` scoped `object`. Though they bear the same name, both are different.

```
void somefunction(classA object)
{                    // ^^^^^^   Is a copy of the parameter passed. 
   object.seta(5); // This call isn't actually modifying the original parameter passed.

}// life time of argument,object, ends here.
```

You should pass it by reference instead if you wish to modify parameter passed itself.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with "local functions" (functions defined *inside* other functions). This is simply about public and private members.

If a member is `private`, then it can *only* be accessed by other members of that class, or by explicit friends of the class.

Answer (score 1):

private means that only member functions and friends can access it.  Both must be listed in the class declaration, but are not:

```
class classA
{

public:

private:
   int a;
   seta(int x);
};
```

Being in the same file doesn't make the function a part of the class -- only the class declaration is used to determine what has access.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, to answer your primary question:

> If the function is private and only this class is calling it, why is
>   there an issue?

The issue is that `private` class members can only be invoked by other members of that class.  The function `somefunction()` is not a member of `classA` and therefore does not have access to private member `seta()`.

As an aside, you should also think carefully about what you're doing when passing `object` to `somefunction()` from `main`. You're passing `object` by value, so you're creating a copy of `object` scoped to `somefunction()` which will be destroyed as soon as `somefunction()` terminates. IS that what you want?

I suspect that you're intending to pass `object` to `somefunction()` from `main` by reference, in which case you need to declare `somefunction()` as

```
void somefunction(classA &object)
```

Answer (score 1):

`seta(int x)` is a private member of `ClassA`, so only `ClassA` or a `friend class` of `ClassA` can access to this member. `somefunction()` is none of them.